# How to assign LDAP user to local group "users"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap

We have machines with both local and LDAP accounts. Every computer has a HDD mounted where the local group "users" has reading and writing permissions. How can I add all the LDAP users to that group "users"?

Comment: Are all of your "users" groups the same (e.g., same gid)? Then you could add the group to LDAP, and add them the normal way.

Comment: Probably not, since they are on different machines and not necessarily have the same gid as far as I know

Comment: Do you have centralized enough config management to make using `pam_group` (etc.) work?

Answer (score 4):

You add them to the group like you would do any user.

`usermod -aG users username`

Example.

```
[root@red pub]# usermod -aG jabber nazu
[root@red pub]# grep jabber /etc/group
jabber:x:499:nazu
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to add them all at once? I guess there are >10 LDAP users and it would be tedious to run this command on every machine. What is `-aG` option doing by the way?

Comment: `usermod` doesn't allow multiple names on the same command. Do a for loop. -a does an append, -G is groups.

Comment: @mcExchange:  When you want to get details on a command such as its parameters, you go in a shell and type `man usermod` (current case) and in there you search for the `-a` and `-G` options.  Searching in `man` is done like in `vi` with a `/` (continue searching is done with `n` for next).

Answer (score 1):

So our current workaround is first checking the group-id of the LDAP users using

```
getent passwd
```

In our case one can easily see the LDAP group id

```
someLdapUser:x:1000023:1000001:/media/remote_home/someLdapUser
```

Now while being mounted, one can change the group permissions of the local data partition (`/media/data`) to that id using

```
sudo chown :1000001 /media/data
```

Only problem is that now the local users cannot write to the partition anymore, since their group id looks differently:

```
someLocalUser:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/someLocalUser:/bin/bash
```

I tried to add the local user to the `1000001` group, but it doesn't work since the `adduser` commands expects a group name and not a number... If anyone has an idea for that, it would be great.